# Formatting MYSQL Date in PHP inside Array

Tags: php, mysql

How can I format the date to m-d-Y when I have an array like this?

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<div>' . $row['date'] . '</div><hr/><br/>';

    $array[] = $row['need'];
}
```

Comment: what format is your date? Did you try something?

Comment: @Michael the current output reads like this 2015-11-24 18:55:29

Comment: Would like it formated like this 11/25/15

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you want it formatted. Here is an example.

```
<?php echo date('m d, Y',strtotime($row['date']))?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use strtotime() and date():

```
$newdate = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($row['date']))
```

Comment: How do I store $row['date'] as $original date?

Comment: $originaldate = $row['date'];

Comment: if I change the echo to $newdate it doesn't loop through the array properly.